# Issues with encoded video in Chrome playback

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Chrome is very particular about how a video is encoded. An issue I am facing with a specific type of video is `seeked` either does not get called at all or at least within a 20s period of time within certain frames.

I can consistently repeat this issue using this muxer https://github.com/redbrain/ytdl-core-muxer/blob/main/index.js

When I paint each frame in puppeteer Lambda there are certain frames where either `seeked`  never gets called or the 20s timeout is called before the frame can resolve.

Here is an example of a log sequence for this particular frame that fails [image]

When I re-encode this video, simply by running `ffmpeg -i VIDEO_URL` then try with the new one there are no issues.

In order to see the differences on a frame level I run `ffprobe -show_frames goodvideo.mp4 > good.txt` && `ffprobe -show_frames badvideo.mp4 > bad.txt` and here is what I see with the frames around the 117s mark where the first sign of corruption occurs

**Good Frame @ 117s**

```
[FRAME]
media_type=video
stream_index=0
key_frame=0
pts=7020013
pts_time=117.000217
pkt_dts=7020013
pkt_dts_time=117.000217
best_effort_timestamp=7020013
best_effort_timestamp_time=117.000217
pkt_duration=1001
pkt_duration_time=0.016683
pkt_pos=27029408
pkt_size=1741
width=1920
height=1080
pix_fmt=yuv420p
sample_aspect_ratio=1:1
pict_type=B
coded_picture_number=7014
display_picture_number=0
interlaced_frame=0
top_field_first=0
repeat_pict=0
color_range=tv
color_space=bt709
color_primaries=bt709
color_transfer=bt709
chroma_location=left
[/FRAME]
```

**Bad Frame @ 117s**

```
[FRAME]
media_type=video
stream_index=0
key_frame=0
pts=117000
pts_time=117.000000
pkt_dts=117000
pkt_dts_time=117.000000
best_effort_timestamp=117000
best_effort_timestamp_time=117.000000
pkt_duration=16
pkt_duration_time=0.016000
pkt_pos=20592998
pkt_size=18067
width=1920
height=1080
pix_fmt=yuv420p
sample_aspect_ratio=1:1
pict_type=P
coded_picture_number=7011
display_picture_number=0
interlaced_frame=0
top_field_first=0
repeat_pict=0
color_range=tv
color_space=bt709
color_primaries=bt709
color_transfer=bt709
chroma_location=left
[/FRAME]
```

Does anyone know the differences and why the bad frame is causing my rendering function to have issues seeking?

This is how I am muxing the bad video, Im trying to avoid re-encoding, but by re-encoding it seems to fix the issue. Are there any settings I can apply to avoid re-encoding while making the video more durable on Chrome?

```
// default export: the ffmpeg muxer
const ytmux = (link, options: any = {}) => {
  const result = new stream.PassThrough({
    highWaterMark: options.highWaterMark || 1024 * 512
  });

  ytdl.getInfo(link, options).then((info: videoInfo) => {
    let audioStream: Readable = ytdl.downloadFromInfo(info, {
      ...options,
      quality: "highestaudio"
    });
    let videoStream: Readable = ytdl.downloadFromInfo(info, {
      ...options,
      quality: "highestvideo"
    });
    // create the ffmpeg process for muxing
    let ffmpegProcess: any = cp.spawn(
      ffmpegPath.path,
      [
        // supress non-crucial messages
        "-loglevel",
        "8",
        "-hide_banner",
        // input audio and video by pipe
        "-i",
        "pipe:3",

        "-i",
        "pipe:4",

        // map audio and video correspondingly
        "-map",
        "0:v",
        "-map",
        "1:a",

        // no need to change the codec
        "-c",
        "copy",

        // Allow output to be seekable, which is needed for mp4 output
        "-movflags",
        "frag_keyframe+empty_moov",

        "-fflags",
        "+genpts",

        "-f",
        "matroska",

        "pipe:5"
      ],
      {
        // no popup window for Windows users
        windowsHide: true,
        stdio: [
          // silence stdin/out, forward stderr,
          "inherit",
          "inherit",
          "inherit",
          // and pipe audio, video, output
          "pipe",
          "pipe",
          "pipe"
        ]
      }
    );

    audioStream.pipe(ffmpegProcess.stdio[4]);
    videoStream.pipe(ffmpegProcess.stdio[3]);
    ffmpegProcess.stdio[5].pipe(result);
  });
  return result;
};
```

Comment: Why is it `-f matroska` instead of `-f mp4`? Maybe that'll fix your problem (or one part of it)...

Comment: I've tried both to no avail... There are benefits to `-f mp4` and `-pix_fmt yuv420p` they help with playback, but the `seeked` issue still remains. I did try `-bf 3` and I thought it worked, one time it seemed to have worked, but then kept failing after

Comment: I also think maybe the version of Chromium needs to be updated. Currently using `90.0.4403.0`

Comment: I'll take a look when I have time in a few days.

Comment: Instead of relying on Chrome seeking I am using FFMPEG to break the video down into images, then painting them on the browser as images which is way more reliable.